# sentence in predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

“If all politicians are showmen and no showman is sincere then some politicians are
insincere.”
Ans: F:= $(\forall x\,(P(x) \to ShMan(x)) \land \not \exists y\,( ShMan(y) \to Sinc(y))) \to \exists z\,(P(z) \to \neg Sinc(z)) $

Is the resulting formula valid in classical logic?

my answer is yes. I have checked like : $\neg(F)$ which shows it's unSat $ \to $ F is valid

Prove your answer in terms of semantical arguments. can someone explain it for me. I mean how do it? answer is it's not valid but How to show it?

Answer (score 3):

You actually need modifications in your translation:  The connectives in each existential (or negation of existence) need to be $\land$, not $\rightarrow$.

I'll use $S(x)$ to mean "is a showman", and $H(x)$ to mean "x is sincere (honest)". Then what follows is the correct translation of the statement “If all politicians are showmen and no showman is sincere then some politicians are insincere.”

$$(\forall x\,(P(x) \to S(x)) \land \not \exists y\,( S(y) \land H(y))) \to \exists z\,(P(z) \land \lnot H(z))$$

The correctly translated implication is invalid, because we do not have enough information to prove the *existence* of a politician, let alone the existence of a politician that is also insincere. *This is a fine point.

I'll repeat @Andreas Blass's nice semantic argument (see comment below) here:  "A quick way to formulate the semantic argument is to imagine an ideal world, where everyone is sincere and there are no politicians and no showmen."

Comment: A quick way to formulate the semantic argument is to imagine an ideal world, where everyone is sincere and there are no politicians and no showmen.

Comment: @GitGud Now what I've posted is what I want (and wanted) to say.

Comment: @amWhy Yeah, I noticed as soon as you fixed it and immediately up voted.

Comment: @AndreasBlass What a wonderful world that would be!  ;-)